# Execute code in django as a timed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a message board application that needs to collect and display messages without any user input or action. I am currently doing this by refreshing the page using the html meta refresh tag. I realize that this is not a great solution. This is the relevant section that I want to run frequently without refreshing the page.

```
{% if grams_list %} #if there exists any messages for the user
  {% for g in grams_list %} #for each message
      <h2 class="gram-display">{{ g.message }}</h2> #display the message
  {% endfor %}
{% else %} #otherwise display this nice picture
  <h2 id="nograms" class="gram-display">No grams right now.</h2>
  <img id="bird" src="/static/cardinal_from_pixabay.jpg">
{% endif %}
```

Is this the sort of thing that could be accomplished with JavaScript? I know that it is possible to have javascript trigger a Javascript function every so often, but is this possible to trigger this event? Alternately, does Django have some built-in function that does this? Could it be handled by signals (I looked at signals but didn't really understand them, though they looked like they had potential to be useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django signals can not do this. Look at jQuery.load() (http://api.jquery.com/load/) for what is probably the simplest method to do this that is similar to what you're doing now (you'll have to put the template as a separate url/view).

Answer (score 0):

Pushing data from the server to client is fairly straightforward using Websockets. If an event of some kind happens and you need to notify the user, you can use Websockets for that.

The [Django Channels project](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is one way of using Websockets with Django. I've also heard of people using Tornado for this. Or alternatively you can send a message to a Redis queue and have a Node.js script pick up the message and broadcast it to users. All of these are viable options, but as Channels is an official Django project it's probably the safest bet. You can then use Javascript on the client side to carry out any necessary action as a result.

Signals are basically a way to trigger a function on certain events eg a certain model being saved. They aren't directly broadcastable to the client side but they could be used to call this functionality. Basically you could use a signal to send a message via Websockets to the client side.